# Find peak from square pyramid angles and cross sector

Tags: geometry

I understand that this is basic geometry problem but I'm not able to find a solution.

I have a square pyramid described in form of rays from the peak (`r1`, `r2`, `r3`, `r4`).
I know the cross section points (`p1`, `p2`, `p3`, `p4`) and the `section center`.

I try better explanation with an hand-made image (sorry for the quality):
[image]

I need to find the peak position. 
I can calculate the angle between the line `peak`-`section center` so that I can use right triangle formulas but I don't figure out how to find the length of it.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the right answer using the [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines). Considering the right-triangle with points `peak`, `p1`, `section center`.

I have:
- the base (half diagonal of the bounding box), the distance between `p1` and `section center`
- the angle between segments `peak`-`p1` and `peak`-`section center` and I can calculate the height of the triangle.